# Reducing sfController::forward execution time

Tags: symfony-1.4

In a Symfony 1.4 project, (monitored using New Relic) some pages are slow due to long `sfController::forward` execution time.

I have inspected `sfController::forward` method to see anything that can increase execution time for specific pages though I could not find any, also checked [Symfony Internals](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/10-Symfony-Internals) document no clue there either.

So the question is, what increases the execution time of `sfController::forward` and how to reduce it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: It appears that this time was spent by php-fpm while request is waiting for worker process.